# Why am I receiving a 404 error when accessing a Web API in production with a .NET MVC 5 Web APP in production but not development

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

First time API developer, New to MVC developer

API is on Production server, can be accessed successfully using link in Chrome ex. http://.../reportservicesapi/api/group

MVC project on developer machine accesses the API on the production server successfully using the same link and is able to display the data.

MVC project published to Production server returns the HTTP error "Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

Both projects have Windows Authentication enabled <-- company intranet and required process

MVC project

APIPath = "http://.../reportservicesapi/api/"

Url = "http://.../reportservicesapi/api/Group?includeDeleted=false"

Call to the API

```
public class ServiceRepository
{
    private static HttpClient Client { get; set; }

    public ServiceRepository()
    {
        Client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic

        })
        {
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)
        };
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["APIPath"].ToString());

    }

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponse(string Url)
    {
        try
        {

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Url);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await Client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string tst = ex.Message;
            return new HttpResponseMessage();
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting to receive a json that I can then serialize into a model and display in my MVC app. However, I'm receiving  a 404 error instead.

I've tried many different techniques but as I said I'm new to API and MVC. Please, any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: This might seem a bit weird but I think you're constructing the HttpClient in the constructor of the of your ServiceRepository class, however, the GetResponse method is static, this means that when you can GetResponse, there's a chance that the CLient property of the class be null. Also you might even want to look at your GetResponse method, using HttpClient.GetAsync should be more semantically correct than HttpClient.SendAsync. I would use the using() {} syntax instead of keeping the Http Client as a static property.

Comment: Thank you Himanshu Pant,  Such a beginner error to make. However, this was not the issue. I'm sure it was not helping the situation though.

Comment: If you have access to the production server, try running fiddler on it and check to see if the url was valid or not(copy the url and paste in the browser). 9/10 it's the value of the url in the Configuration, which causes this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately fiddler is not allowed in my company. would the URL i'm sending into the ServiceRepository possibly be changed based on how the HttpClient is being constructed?  I'll see if I can convince the powers that be to allow a one time use. Thank you.

Comment: I found out that someone had added a binding on the server to go to a specific I.P. address. once that was removed I was able to access the API as I needed to